# Push all dates back by 7 days in a project (project 2013)

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I am doing a project for college and I am being forced to use project 2013... I have got a very basic understanding, but I need to push all dates from a certain point back by 7 days, I was wondering if this was possible? I was very optimistic about my dates and I am now in need to of changing the dates, but don't want to do so manually if possible. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The simple way is to insert a milestone, make all subsequent tasks depend on the milestone and then push the milestone back 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tasks are linked: if all tasks in the project are to be changed, go to Project Ribbon, Project Information, and change the project start date.

If not all tasks need to be moved, select the tasks you wish to move and choose Update Project.  Choose "Reschedule uncomplete work to start after", set the new start date and ensure you have "selected tasks" selected.

You can also select the tasks and use the Move Tasks command on the Task ribbon.

Answer (score -1):

OR... Go to the project tab and click on "Move Project." Put in a new start date and everything should adjust accordingly.